# Remove First 12 Characters from each list item when populate ListBox

Tags: c#, list, listbox

How can i remove the first 12 Characters of each List item.

I have one `LisBox` named `MyListBox`, and one `list` named `MyList`

all the `items` on my `list` start like this `userPT_Test/NAMEOFTHEITEM` i need to remove the 1st 12 characters when populate my listbox i have tryed like this:

```
MyListBox.DataSource = MyList.Remove(0, 11);
```

But is not working and is giving me one error: `Error 14: No overload for method 'Remove' takes 2 arguments`

I need to remove this part `userPT_Test/` and only populate my `listbox` with the `NAMEOFTHEITEM`...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using Linq:

```
MyListBox.DataSource = MyList.Select(x=> x.Substring(12)).ToList();
```

If you want safe Substring (in case Length not guaranteed), you can use more linq Magic:

```
myList.Select(x => new String(x.Skip(12).ToArray()));
```